# Saving matrix in double precision from OpenCV (C++) for Matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv

I want to compare matrices created from OpenCV with the ones in Matlab. If the matrices are uint8, Saving them as pgm images would do the trick. But my matrices are CV_64FC1 (double) that can't be saved as images. Is there any easy way to save my double matrix for reading in Matlab?

Comment: easier than file output you mean?

Comment: @gokcehan I don't think CV_64FC1 can be saved. Am I right?

Comment: i don't think he means as images. Output the raw data to file

Comment: well, it has been a long time since I touched opencv but can't you just print the values and save them to a text file? that's what I meant.

Comment: @gokcehan That's tough as they are in double precision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one from OpenCV samples.

```
Mat r
std::stringstream ss;
ss << format(r,"csv") << endl << endl;
myFile << ss.str();
// or even this
myFile << format(r,"csv") << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Hey, I am applying your way, but I am getting strange values in my text file, my matrices are CV_64F: 51.0225219726563219.4757385253906-722.7874145507813-375.035

Answer (score 0):

Just write the intensity of each pixel into a file and read it with MATLAB using `importdata`.